# Matlab: Finding distance to nearest TRUE value in a matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, distance

Lets assume I have a logical matrix A (about 1000x1000 size) and want to find for each element the euclidean distance to the nearest TRUE value. How can that be done fast in Matlab?

E.g if i have matrix A:

```
A = [1 0 0 0
     0 1 1 1
     0 0 0 0
     0 0 1 0]
```

Then what i want is:

```
B = [0 1 1 1
     1 0 0 0
     1.41 1 1 1
     2 1 0 1]
```

One possibility would be imdilate(), but then i would have to dilate a MxN Matrix with a 2Mx2N Matrix, which would take way too long.

I tried calculating the distances from each element to each element==1 using pdist2() and then taking the minimum but that turned out to use way too much memory.

Any suggestions? I would also settle for a solution that just approximates it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`bwdist`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwdist.html) function in the Image Processing Toolbox does precisely this

```
A = [1 0 0 0 
     0 1 1 1
     0 0 0 0
     0 0 1 0];

B = bwdist(A);

%   0.00000   1.00000   1.00000   1.00000
%   1.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000
%   1.41421   1.00000   1.00000   1.00000
%   2.00000   1.00000   0.00000   1.00000
```

Comment: My googeling skills definitely need to get better. Thx a lot!